# On the definition of complete space in Atiyah-Macdonald's book

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra, topological-groups

In Chapter 10 of Atiyah-Macdonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* they define, for a first-countable abelian topological group $G$, the **completion** $\hat G$ of $G$ to be the quotient  group of all Cauchy sequences modulo null sequences. Then they define the notion of completeness by saying that $G$ is complete if the map $\phi:G\to\hat G$ mapping an element $g\in G$ to the constant sequence $(g)_n$ is an isomorphism. Being an isomorphism means:

- $\phi$ is **surjective**, this is, any Cauchy sequence in $G$ converges: indeed, given a Cauchy sequence $(g_n)_n$ in $G$, it is the image of some $g\in G$ via $\phi$, and it is easy to see that $g$ is a limit of $(g_n)_n$, so it converges.
- $\phi$ is **injective**, this is, $G$ is Hausdorff: since $\ker\phi$ is the closure of $\{0\}$, so points are closed if and only if $\ker\phi$ is 0.

The first point (namely that $\phi$ is surjective) is precisely the usual definition of completeness in metric spaces: all Cauchy sequences converge. The second point (that $\phi$ is injective) seems to be an independent statement. However, I have not been successful in finding an example of a group $G$ which is complete in the metric space sense but with $\phi$ not injective (i.e., not Hausdorff).

> Can you give an example of a non-Hausdorff first countable abelian topological group which is complete in the sense that Cauchy sequences converge?

Comment: How is Cauchy sequence defined in this context? Using a uniform structure?

Comment: @LeeMosher Sorry, I should have included the definition in the question: $(a_n)_n$ is Cauchy if for each neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ there exists an $n_0$ such that $a_m-a_n\in U$ for all $m,n\geq n_0$.

Comment: Which is the definition given in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence#In_topological_groups

Comment: Okay, so that is indeed equivalent to a uniform structure definition, but more nicely stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this for an example: $G = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with the indiscrete topology. All sequences converge, in fact all sequences converge to the identity element *and* to the non-identity element. The only neighborhood of the identity is $G$ itself, so all sequences are Cauchy, and all sequences are null. It follows that $\hat G$ is the trivial group, and $\phi : G \to \hat G$ is not injective.

Comment: That works! Thank you!

Comment: What about an example of a non-Hausdorff abelian topological group where every Cauchy sequence has a *unique* limit?

Comment: Sounds like a good question for another post.